# how to convert 2 dimensional list into list of dictionary in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a 2 dimensional list of list but I would like the list inside the list to be dictionary

```
list1 = [["ab","cd"],["ef","gh"]]    
#code here,
print(output_list_of_dict)
#output should be ...
#[{"name": "ab", "phone":"cd"},{"name": "ef", "phone":"gh"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this directly with a comprehension and tuple unpacking:

```
list1 = [["ab","cd"],["ef","gh"]]
output_list_of_dict = [{"name": x, "phone": y} for x, y in list1]
```

Comment: Thanks!, this is the answer than I want.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [["ab","cd"],["ef","gh"]]

res = []
for item in list1:
    res.append({"name": item[0], "phone": item[1]})
print(res)
```

If you want to use list comprehension for a more "pythonic" way:

```
list1 = [["ab","cd"],["ef","gh"]]

res = [{"name": item[0], "phone": item[1]} for item in list1]

print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution:

```
list1 = [["ab","cd"],["ef","gh"]]    

output = []

for item in list1:
    dic = {}
    dic["name"] = item[0]
    dic["phone"] = item[1]

    output.append(dic)


print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

`dict` and `zip` will also work

```
l = ["name", "phone"]
[dict(zip(l,i)) for i in list1]
```

Comment: Nice. I'd rename `l` to something like `headings`, but +1 regardless.